# how to make narrator to read the controls inside stackpanel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, screen-readers, narrator

Windows narrator doesn't read the contents of stack panel, below is the snippet of stack panel

```
 <StackPanel Name="StackAutoUpdatePanel" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="6">
      <Label  Name="SettingsAutoUpdate_Label" Content="SettingsAutoUpdate" />
      <TextBlock Name="SettingsAutoUpdateDesc_Txtblk" Text="SettingsAutoUpdateDesc"></TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```

During keyboard navigation, narrator(also checked with screen reader NVDA) is not reading the text of TextBlock or Content of Label since it is inside the stackpanel. It also doesn't read the Grid's contents. Anything am I missing here in order to make narrator read the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Narrator or NVDA are not expected to read the contents by itself you need to enable and use Scan mode.

On Narrator, enable it by pressing the `Caps lock + Space`, use the key `P` to go one paragraph at a time.